# C++ Preprocessor Infix Stingified Macro Function Value

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor

I am working on a sizable JNI based project. JNI requires certain **C** function names to match the related JAVA function names. Example of what I'm talking about:

**Example.java**

```
package com.example.app;
...
class Example {
    public static native void doSomething();
}
```

**Example.c**

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_example_app_Example_doSomething(...) {...}
```

I'm using macros to simplify the notation:

```
#define J_DEF(name, ...) JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_example_app_Example_##name(..., __VA_ARGS)
```

But I've run in to a problem when trying to replace the `..com_example_app...` part in the macro with another macros return value like that:

```
#define J_PACKAGE(separator) "com" separator "example" separator "app"
#define J_DEF(name, ...) JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_##J_PACKAGE("_")##_##name(..., __VA_ARGS)
```

Is there anyway to correctly simulate the syntax, I've written? It doesn't seem to work.

P.S. I am using the J_PACKAGE macro for other parts of the code as well, just with different separators.

**Example 1**

```
#define J_DEF(name, ...) JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_example_app_Example_##name(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj, __VA_ARGS__)

J_DEF(myFunction); // generates: JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_example_app_Example_myFunction(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj);
J_DEF(myFunction, int x); // generates: JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_example_app_Example_myFunction(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj, int x);
```

**Example 2**

```
#define J_PACKAGE(separator) "com" separator "example" separator "app"
#define J_DEF(name, ...) JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_##J_PACKAGE(_)##_##name(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj, __VA_ARGS__)

J_DEF(myFunction); // generates: void  Java_J_PACKAGE(_)_myFunc(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj  );
// instead I need to generate JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_example_app_Example_myFunction(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj);
```

Comment: What does "It doesn't seem to work" mean ? Can you give an example input, the output you expect and the output you actually get ?

Comment: you seem to use string constants as method name. Use ## in J_PACKAGE and remove "

Comment: I've updated the question with concrete examples.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this will solve your issue:

```
#define J_PACKAGE(sep) com ## sep ## example ##  sep ##  app
#define JDEF2(A, B) JNIEXPORT void JNICALL java_##A##_##B
#define JDEF1(A, B)  JDEF2( A, B)
#define J_DEF(C, ...) JDEF1( J_PACKAGE(_), C) (JNIEnv* env, jobject obj, __VA_ARGS__)
```